# Changing a reference in Java

Tags: java, reference, copy

I'm trying to develop a Data Structure in Java and I'm facing a problem that I just can't solve. I have a reference to an object, and, after copying it, I want to change the original reference using only the copy. For example:

```
Point a = new Point(0,0);
Point b = a;
b = new Point(5,5);
```

I want "a" to point to "new Point(5,5)" too, and not only "b". Is there anyway to do that?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Point a; // no need to instantiate
Point b = new Point(5,5);
a = b;
```

Comment: This technically answers the question, but I doubt that this answer is useful at all. Obviously, he doesn't have access to `a` when he creates a new point and assign it to `b`.

Comment: @Daniel, keep in mind that this is a flat copy, so changes in b will be seen in a and vice versa. also this may affect garbage collection in case one of the references is held beyond the scope where the assignment happened. since you say copy you may want to have a look at `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()`

Comment: gefei, I fear I couldn't explain the problem correctly. There are a lot of references running on the thread, and I don't know which is being copied by "b", so "a = b" won't do here.

Answer (score 2):

If you make setter methods you could do:

```
Point a = new Point(0,0);
Point b = a;
//b and a now reference the same point
b.setX(5);
b.setY(5);
//Now we have made changes to the point referenced by b
//Since a references the same point, these changes will
//also apply to a
```

---

The problem with your example is that you are doing `new Point(x,y)`.

```
Point a = new Point(0,0);
Point b = a;
//At this point only one instance of Point exists.
//Both a and b reference the same Point.
//Any change you do to that point will be reflected through both a and b.
b = new Point(5,5);
//Now you have created a second instance of point.
//a and b reference the different points.
```

---

So, in summary, you must understand the difference between modifying the already existing point and creating a new point and letting only one of the references reference the new point.

Comment: where is variable 'a' getting the new Point values

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Added an explanation of what happens in your example.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem here is that "a" isn't being indirectly pointed to a new object. But thank you very much for your help anyway.

Comment: @DanielBastos That is because you have clearly written in your code: **Let** ***a*** **reference a new 0,0 point**, then **Let** ***b*** **reference the already existing 0,0 point**. Then **Let** ***b*** **reference a new 5,5 point**.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in Java. You could simulate it creating a wrapper for Point:

```
public class PointWrapper {
    private Point point;

    public PointWrapper(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public Point getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(Point point) {
        this.point = point;
    }
}

PointWrapper a = new PointWrapper(new Point(0,0));
PointWrapper b = a;
b.setPoint(new Point(5,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `new Point(5,5)`, a new reference is assigned to `b`, so you'll have different references for `a` and `b`.

The only way to mantain a reference to the same instance, so that changes to `b` are "visible" also to `a`, is to set new values (5,5) to the original object (as also explained from **Alderath**):

```
b.setX(5);
b.setY(5);
```